# I have an data set in google sheets , i want to split of data in specific groups of Size X (Varies according to my Requirement), on the of an column?

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, excel-formula, split

I have an data set in google sheets , i want to split of data in specific groups of Size X (Varies according to my Requirement), on the of an column ? I need Formula for either Excel or GOOGLE sheets !

I have tried using SET and OFFSET Function but it is not working

Comment: Post few of your sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: I would be looking at the use of index() with match() - always avoid offset().

Comment: tbh - unless I've totally missed something, I thought it was a great Q that some may have voted down due to brevity / and corresponding lack of understanding or familiarity with this type of problem -- otherwise v. good Q - I suspect there is quicker way than below (there is I didn't have to lay out the counts as well, but might as well for completeness)  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9iKUbp8aBV6JgIDNmPw?e=PxxXdN) /screenshot(s) refer.
Caveat/notes: No validation; Office 365 compatibility req.
Assumes numerical values being grouped in consecutive 'buckets'.

---

*Balls to the wall:*

```
=LET(x0_,Table13[Value],
x1_,SORT(UNIQUE(x0_)),x1_B,x1_,e0_,COUNTIFS(x0_,"<"&x1_B),e1_,ROUNDDOWN(e0_/$E$1,0),e2_,UNIQUE(e1_),x2_,INDEX(x1_,MATCH(e2_,e1_,0)), x2_a,INDEX(x2_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x2_)-1,,2)),x2_B,INDEX(x2_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x2_)-1)),
e3_,COUNTIFS(x0_,">="&x2_B,x0_,"<"&x2_a),e4_,ROUNDDOWN(e3_/$E$1,0),x3_,FILTER(x2_B,--(e4_>0)),
x3_A,INDEX(x3_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x3_)-1,,2)), x3_B,INDEX(x3_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x3_)-1)),x2_L,INDEX(x3_A,ROWS(x3_A)),
e5_1,COUNTIFS(x0_,">="&x3_B,x0_,"<"&x3_A),e6_1,COUNTIFS(x0_,">="&x2_L), h1_,VSTACK(x3_B,">="&x2_L),h2_,VSTACK(e5_1,e6_1),HSTACK(h1_,h2_))
```

[image: Sample pic]

---

*Breakdown e.g.*

Whilst function may look intimidating, several parts are repeated or similar but subtly different to accommodate fiddly calcs at the low/high pts (end-values).

Salient features: meat 'n bones reside with the `rounddown(value, bucket_size)`, this will set the cumulative count, `e0_`, of ordered, unique values, `x1_`, to `e1_` which can only increment if the original (cum.) counts increase by at least the bucket size.

Consider the following example:

1. Unique ordered values = 1,2,3,4,... (`x1_`), corresponding to cum. counts of 488,499, 501, 505 (`e0_)`.
2. Apply rounddown(*/500,0) to counts (e1*), obtain this: 0, 0, 1, 1;
3. Ignore duplicate values, i.e. e2_, unique(e1_)
4. Obtain the corresponding value from which this was derived (`index(x1_,match(e2_e1_,0)`)
5. We end up with values that are spaced such that the count of underlying/original values between each is at least 500 (bucket); and likewise for the final value (for which the count of underlying values, col A, is larger than 500)

---

*Checks:*

- **Bucket size 1000**

Bucket size: 1000 - should result in fewer groups, none of which should comprise fewer than 1k:

[image: bucket 1000]

- **Bucket = 10** - more groups that comprise at least 10 in each:

[image: Bucket 10]

Ta

---